# How to download/search mailing list archives for Apache projects?

Tags: email, apache-kafka, mailing-list

On joining a Apache mailing list, one get's only the mails after the subscription. I want to go through the existing archives in the list as they may already have answers to the questions that I have or may have in future.

For eg. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/ 
The archives are available for the project here but I can not search through.

Is there any way, I can search these mailing list online ( I tried google, but it's points to the particular reply and it get's hard to locate the complete thread ) or if they can be downloaded, imported in a client and then searched locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the new url that seems to be hosted by apache itself: https://lists.apache.org/

Comment: Looks to be dead in 2020 :(

Comment: @thomasa88: yah, that one died. Try using this apache url itself: https://lists.apache.org/

Answer (score 3):

Another option to browse/search all Apache project messages is http://apache.markmail.org/. You can filter messages for a given project with "list:projectname".

Comment: Does not seem to have up-to-date results in 2020. Searching for something I know is in an e-mail from 5 months ago gives no results. (Searching for imxrt should give hits in the nuttx mailing list)